# How to edit and save WPF GridView, to database?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I would like to create editable DataGrid whose cells can either be read-only or editable (by DoubleClicking)...
I want to save all of editted cells to database,(via Entity Framework)...

then in some columns, I need to show a combobox instead of a text field.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on if you using MVVM or not.

Either way you need to determine how you want to save. Is there a save button? Or are edits saved as soon as they are made. (last one is awful for your DB but up to you)

Edits produce an event you can capture. Also clicking on save button produces an event.

**SAVE BUTTON**
So lets assume you want a save button.

Well then when the button click event occurs you would call the code to save to your db. Without knowing your db I can't really tell you much more except this should be farmed to a different thread so it doesn't happen on the UI thread. Look at Task.Run for more info.

**SAVE ON EDIT**
Basically the same as above but you will ending up talking to your db much more often. Each keypress really, which is why it's harder on your db.
Basically your trapping the keypress or keyup events and then saving the info to your DB.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I don't use MVVM, and my Database is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

use this code :

```
public class Window2Viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Window2Viewmodel()
        {
            MyDbContext myDbContext = new MyDbContext();
            Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(myDbContext.Customers.Include("Cars").ToList());
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                myDbContext.SaveChanges();
            });
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers;

        public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
        {
            get { return _customers; }
            set
            {
                if (_customers != value)
                {
                    _customers = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallermemberNmae]string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    }
```

And this XAML Code :

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:Window2Viewmodel x:Key="VM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VM}}">
        <DataGrid Name="testDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FName}"  Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LName}"  Header="Lastname"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Save" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you give me complete example code?